# Using Media Fragments and preventing the browser from reloading the targeted HTMLMediaElement

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, electron, html5-video

I am working on a program, were i have to use media fragment to keep the user within a particular starting and ending time frame. And the user will be able to set the start time and the end time.

```
const path = require("path");

const createFragment = (startEnd,location) => {      
    const fragmentEl = document.createElement("div");
    fragmentEl.setAttribute("data-fragment", startEnd);
    fragmentEl.classList.add("akara-media-fragment");
    fragmentEl.style.left = `${location}px`;
    akaraTimeIndicator.appendChild(fragmentEl);
    if ( startEnd === "start" ) {
       const reg = new RegExp(`${path.extname(video.src)}$`);

       // how can i prevent the browser from reloading the video element, i want the fragment to work on the fly
       video.src = video.src.replace(reg, `${path.extname(video.src)}#t=the time frame goes here`);
    }
};


akaraTimeIndicator.addEventListener("contextmenu", evt => {

    const { left , right } = akaraTimeIndicator.getBoundingClientRect();

    const firstFragment = akaraTimeIndicator.querySelector("[data-fragment=start]");
    const lastFragment = akaraTimeIndicator.querySelector("[data-fragment=end]");

    // * 100 to get calculation
    const XAxis = (evt.clientX / 1000) * 100;

    if ( ! firstFragment ) {
        createFragment("start", evt.clientX);
        return;
    }

    const firstFrag = parseInt(firstFragment.style.left);
    const lastFrag = lastFragment ? parseInt(lastFragment.style.left) : null;

    if ( evt.clientX <  firstFrag ) {
        firstFragment.remove();
        createFragment("start", evt.clientX);
        return;
    }

    if ( lastFrag &&
         (evt.clientX > lastFrag
          || evt.clientX < lastFrag
         )
       ) {
        lastFragment.remove();
        createFragment("end", evt.clientX);
        return;
    }

    if ( evt.clientX === firstFrag ) {
        if ( lastFrag ) lastFragment.setAttribute("data-fragment", "start");
        firstFragment.remove();
        akara_emit.emit("akara::fragment:removed", "first");
        return;
    }

    if ( lastFrag && ( evt.clientX === lastFrag ) ) {
        lastFragment.remove();
        akara_emit.emit("akara::fragment:remove", "last");
        return;
    }

    createFragment("end", evt.clientX);
    return;
});
```

The process for setting the media fragment is a little bit more involved, but the major question is **is there any possible way to set the fragment without the browser reloading the HTMLMediaElement element**

Comment: Not posting this as an answer, since I am not sure if I got the question right - but can't you use Media Source Extensions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API)  and just manipulate the fragments in client-side javascript as SourceBuffers?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis am actually talking about media fragments (specifying a playback range) [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery#Specifying_playback_range)

Comment: well that most likely will trigger reloading. As far as I see, the browser must at least make a request to verify that the content has not changed, so... if you would manipulate the fragments in the client side js, you provide media segments directly to the browser so you bypass such checks.